# How to check if selected date is a public holiday from this retrieved result

Tags: angularjs

I am having simple angular form with a datepicker. I am calling a service to get all the list of public holidays. How to check if selected date from date picker is in that list or not. If it's in that list show an alert "Selected date is public holiday" And I also want to exclude weekends.

```
<input type="date" name="startDate" ng-model="startDate" required>
```

Angular Function which retrieves list of all public holidays. `response.data` has three fields Id, Description and HolidayDate

```
function publicHolidays() {
            holidayService.GetPublicHolidays().then(function (response) {
                $scope.holidays = response.data;
            })
        }
```

How can see if my start date is in this list of public holidays and if yes show an alert. Also how can I exclude weekends

`response.data` has

[image]

Comment: show `$scope.holidays`

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal modified

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm not really sure what you mean by "exclude weekends" but here's how to check if `$scope.startDate` is a weekend or a holiday every time the date selected changes.

```
<input type="date" name="startDate" ng-model="startDate" ng-change"checkHolidaysAndWeekends()" required>

// Controller
$scope.checkHolidaysAndWeekends = function() {
        if($scope.startDate.getDay() == 6 || $scope.startDate.getDay() == 0)
           { alert('Weekend!') };
        angular.forEach($scope.holidays, function(holiday, key){
           if ($scope.startDate == holiday.holidayDate) 
              { alert("That's a holiday") };
        });            
    };
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error at lambda opertor as It's not recognizing in angular `=>`

Comment: Exclude weekends means Exclude saturday and sunday

Comment: I am getting error at `=> ` as lambda operator is not recoginizing

Comment: Aren't you using a datepicker? If that's the case then you can see if the date you are selecting is a Sat or Sun

Comment: I just took out my `=>`'s

Comment: This answer does not work at this line `if ($scope.startDate = holiday.holidayDate) ` It's looping through results mutliple times and show multiple alerts

Comment: I put another `=` and changed `holiday.HolidayDate` to `holiday.holidayDate`

Comment: `angular.forEach($scope.holidays, function(holiday, key){
           if ($scope.startDate == holiday.holidayDate) 
              { alert("That's a holiday") };
        });          ` This part is not working properly if I selected holiday date..for weekend it works well